# How to use useEffect inside a View in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to use an useEffect inside a return (inside a Text that is inside multiple View to be exact) and from what I know, I must use {...} in order to say that what I write is some code. Howether I got a blank screen without errors and I don't know where is the issue with my code.
Here is the code:

```
const [pass, setPass] = useState(0);
...
 return (
                <View>
                  <FlatList
                    data={letter.description}
                    numColumns={2}
                    keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                      if (pass >= letter.description?.length) {
                        useEffect(() => {
                          setPass((prev) => 0);
                        });
                      }
                      return (
                        <View>
                          <Text>
                            {letter.data[pass]}
                            {"\n"}
                          </Text>
                          <Text>
                            {letter.description[pass]}
                            {useEffect(() => {
                              setPass((prev) => prev + 1);
                            })}

                            {"\n"}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                      );
                    }}
                  />
                </View>
```

letter is my data, but you can ignore it. I just keep it here to explain why I need the pass

Comment: why does it have to be a useEffect and not a func?

Comment: and why inside a text are you using useEffect? this is wrong in many terms

Comment: I want to increment a variable so that each time the text is used, I got variable++ and the  I can do data[variable] in order to get my data

Comment: check my Answer.

Comment: I think that it helped but the 2nd useEffect keep the page white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use useEffect to setState?

just set the state :

```
if (pass >= letter.description?.length) { setPass((prev) => 0); }
```

You can use UseEffect to render your component when you want to render it.

More of this here :  `https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html`